# Check whether the variable is a result of a specific function in R

Tags: r

For example,

```
example.function = function(x){
    return (x+1)}
```

and then I do:

```
test = example.function(2)
```

How can I check whether the variable `test` is the result of the function `example.function` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing the function, you can use **attributes**

```r
example.function = function(x) `attr<-`(x + 1, "created by", "example.function")
```

So that the result is still a completely standard numeric object, but it has an additional attribute:

```r
x <- example.function(2)

x
#> [1] 3
#> attr(,"created by")
#> [1] "example.function"
```

A somewhat more sophisticated method would be to hide the attribute by using S3 dispatching, and creating a specific test function:

```r
example.function <- function(x) `attr<-`(x + 1, "class", "special")

print.special <- function(x) print(as.numeric(x))

is.special <- function(x) class(x) == "special"

x <- example.function(2)

x
#> [1] 3

is.special(x)
#> [1] TRUE
```

If you are asking whether you can tell more generally if an object has come from any particular function, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try `attr<-` + `sys.call` (or `match.call`)

```
example.function = function(x) `attr<-`(x+1,"function call", sys.call()[[1]]))
```

such that

```
> test
[1] 3
attr(,"function call")
[1] "example.function"
```

Comment: I guess you could have `match.call()[[1]]` instead : there's probably no need to convert to character since it prints nicely as is and gives you the option of re-using the function in a subsequent call. But good idea +1